# Spring MVC / Restful services - how to get started

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, hosting

I'd like to build a restful service to return some JSON data to a mobile application. I've worked with Grails in the past - it's pretty much perfect for this - but I'd like to learn Spring for my own purposes, mostly because it's the dominant Java-based server technology. So, I'm thinking about building the service in Spring MVC 3 for my own edification. But, one problem already is my hosting service doesn't support Spring - nor Grails for that matter.  They do support Ruby on Rails and PHP.

My question - how heavy of a learning curve is it to get Spring up and running with a restful service? Is there a really good tutorial/learning resource to learn Spring in a short amount of time? Also, will it be difficult/expensive to find a hosting server? Or should I throw in the towel and go with Ruby or PHP?

Comment: You could also try Spring Roo, as a first step. Its much closer to Grails and once you have a working version, you can generate full source and see how the Spring wiring and controllers, etc. are coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are loads of tutorials and some very good ones as well

[This one](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/20/bootstraping-a-web-application-with-spring-3-1-and-java-based-configuration-part-1/) was recommended by SpringSource a couple of weeks ago. It's in 5 parts so make sure to check out the other ones as well :)

At first glance it might look like alot of work but it really isn't, you do the initial wiring pretty fast and then adding new Controllers are really simple so in long term it's going to be fast and easy.